# Generate 'X' number of pages from object using Nuxt JS / Vue JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I am currently creating a ["Static Generated"](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/#static-generated-pre-rendering-https://nuxtjs.org/guide/#static-generated-pre-rendering-) site using NuxtJS version "^2.0.0" (I believe it to be 2.13.x).

I have created a Vuex 'store' from which I plan to pull data to aid in my static generation process. For example I plan to have an array `Articles` within the store containing an object for each article on the site.

My primary question is this: is is possible to render an 'X' amount of these articles (let's say 5) per page and then have NuxtJS automatically generate a new page to contain the next 5 until the source array (`Articles`) runs out of objects?

I understand that NuxtJS provides route generation, but is it possible for it to also statically generate a new page corresponding to each new route? I believe my request is different from [Dynamic Routes](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing/#dynamic-routes), but please correct me if I am mistaken.

Likewise, config [generate](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-generate#routes) option doesn't seem to exactly fit what I'm describing although I admit I don't fully understand its documentation.

Comment: You have to use dynamic routes, otherwise how are you going to differentiate between the page containing 5 articles from the page containing the next 5 articles ? They are two different pages, right? with different urls?

Comment: I have just realized that I could probably resolve this using dynamic URLs and simply adding logical to pull the first 5 objects from the `Articles` array and then incrementing a global counter and creating a new route. I will give this a shot tomorrow and report back.

Comment: @s4k1b Your comment appeared right after I uploaded. I believe you are correct and I simply misunderstood dynamic routes since I am currently using nested routes for these pages, but now see that I do not need nested routes at all and can solely rely on dynamic routes to fulfill my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to thank @s4k1b for the advice. Some continued reading and their guidance helped me realize that I need to use Dynamic Routing.

I did not realize this at first as I was using nested routing (unnecessarily) for these pages which does not play well with dynamic routing. Substituting the nested routing for dynamic routing allowed me to reference the URL parameters (i.e. /writing/1, the number '1') which I then used in my `v-for` logic to achieve the desired affect.

The end result looks something like this:

```
<post
        v-for="index in postCount" :key="index"
        :showBadge="false"
        :title="projects[index + indexAdjust].title"
        :subtitle="projects[index + indexAdjust].subtitle"
        :date="projects[index + indexAdjust].date"
        :tag="projects[index + indexAdjust].tag"
        :url="projects[index + indexAdjust].url">
        {{ projects[index + indexAdjust].body }}
        </post>
```

...

```
data () {
    return {
      projects: this.$store.state.main.projects,
      blogsPerPage: this.$store.state.main.blogsPerPage,
      router: this.$route.params
    }
  },
  computed: {
    postCount () {
      let value = this.blogsPerPage
      if (parseInt(this.router.page) === Math.ceil(this.projects.length / this.blogsPerPage)) {
        // if on the last page
        value = this.projects.length % this.blogsPerPage
      }
      return value
    },
    indexAdjust () {
      let value = (this.blogsPerPage * (parseInt(this.router.page) - 1)) - 1
      return value
    }
  },
```

Basically: iterate the `post` component for `blogsPerPage` amount of times on each page unless we are on the final page then only loop for the modulus of the total number of posts by the number of postsPerPage to only display the remaining post content.

The `indexAdjust` computed value simply counts the number of posts from our Vuex `store` should have already been rendered on previous pages. For this we take the previous page's number `(parseInt(this.router.page) - 1` and multiply it by the number of posts per page. Since `v-for` starts at **1** when iterating by a static number and not through a Javascript object we subtract by 1 to start at the **0** position in our store Array.